# How can I scale differently different objects in kivy for python using canvas scale?

Tags: python, canvas, kivy, scale

## File name: comicwidgets.kv

```
<StickMan@RelativeLayout>:
     size_hint: None, None
     size: 48,48
     canvas:
          PushMatrix
          Line:
               circle: 24,38,5
          Line:
               points: 24,33,24,15
          Line:
               points: 14,5,24,15
          Line:
               points: 34,5,24,15
          Translate:
               y: 48-8
          Rotate:
               angle: 180
               axis: 1,0,0
          Line:
               points: 14,5,24,15
          Line:
               points: 34,5,24,15
          PopMatrix
```

## File name: drawingspace.kv

```
<DrawingSpace@RelativeLayout>:

     canvas:         
          Scale:
               xyz: (5,5,0)
               origin: 10,15 
          Translate: 
               x: -50             
     StickMan:
          canvas:

               Color:
                    rgba: 1,0,1,1 
               Scale:
                    xyz: (10,10,0)  

          pos: 10,15 



     StickMan:
          canvas:
               Scale:
                    xyz: (8,8,0)
               Color: 
                    rgba: 0,1,1,1  
               Translate: 
                    x: +80           
          pos: 50,15   

     StickMan:
          canvas:
#               Scale:
#                    xyz: 2,2,0
               Color: 
                    rgba: 1,1,1,1     
          pos: 100,15                                  
#     Label:
#          markup: True
#          text: '[size=32px][color=#3e6643]The[/color][sub]Comic[/sub] [i][b]Creator[/b][/i][/size]'
```

Why the scale and translate in the canvaces inside the StickMan object don't work. An how I can apply different scale for the different StickMans

Comment: Define "don't work". Your example doesn't include any drawing that you would see scale.

Comment: I want to scale StickMan object

Comment: You need to put `PushMatrix` ,`Scale` and `Translate` in canvas.before (and probably also your Color instructions), and `PopMatrix` in canvas.after. This will mean the run before and after your main drawing, as opposed to in your example where the extra instructions are all run after the drawing and so do not affect it.